# Installing cusignal on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, conda, cupy, cusignal

I wanted to install the cusignal python package on windows and I was following the instructions on the following github [link](https://github.com/rapidsai/cusignal).

It says to run the following commands:

```
conda create --name cusignal-dev

conda activate cusignal-dev

conda install numpy numba scipy cudatoolkit pip
pip install cupy-cuda101

cd python
python setup.py install
```

But towards the last two lines, I have no idea what and where the setup.py file is located. There is also no such folder called python that is automatically created. Hence, I am unsure how I am supposed to install cusignal library on windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions expect that you first clone the GitHub repository, which has such a `python` folder, then run those instructions, like

```
git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/cusignal.git
cd python
python setup.py install
```

Be sure your environment is activated when doing this.

Comment: I did as you said and now I can see where cusignal is located along with all its functions in the folder. It is just strange that when I open jupyter notebook in the same conda environment and create a new notebook on some other location in my computer and import cusignal, it still says that it does not exist. So it is almost as if I need to copy the entire cusignal folder to different locations.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked just fine for me:

```
 conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge cusignal
```